# Prometheus: the "for" is breaking my test

Tags: unit-testing, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I've this alert which I try to cover by unit tests:

```
- alert: Alert name
  annotations:
    summary: 'Summary.'
    book: "https://link.com"
  expr: sum(increase(app_receiver{app="app_name", exception="exception"}[1m])) > 0
  for: 5m
  labels:
    severity: 'critical'
    team: 'myteam'
```

This test scenario is failing each time until the `for: 5m` will be commented in the code. In this case, it'll be successful.

```
rule_files:
  - ./../../rules/test.yml

evaluation_interval: 1m

tests:
  - interval: 1m
    input_series:
      - series: 'app_receiver{app="app_name", exception="exception"}'
        values: '0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'
      - series: 'app_receiver{app="app_name", exception="exception"}'
        values: '0 0 0 0 0 10 20 40 60 80'
    alert_rule_test:
      - alertname: Alert name
        eval_time: 5m
        exp_alerts:
          - exp_labels:
              severity: 'critical'
              team: 'myteam'
            exp_annotations:
              summary: 'Summary.'
              book: "https://link.com"
```

The result of this test:

```
FAILED:
    alertname:Alert name, time:5m, 
        exp:"[Labels:{alertname=\"Alert name\", severity=\"critical\", team=\"myteam\"} Annotations:{book=\"https://link.com\", summary=\"Summary.\"}]", 
        got:"[]
```

Can someone please help me fix this test and explain a failure reason?

Comment: your alert has to keep triggering during 5 minutes because of the `for: 5m`. But your test is for 1 minute `evaluation_interval: 1m` or `interval: 1m`. I am not very into unit tests for prometheus + alertmanager, but I would change the interval to test for greater than 5 minutes and see what happens.

Comment: Hey @Felipe. Thx for attention on this question. Yes, I tried to increase `interval` more than `10m` but nothing results.